# Can i extend object type in graphql lighthouse-php?

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-7, laravel-lighthouse

I am using lighthouse-php with laravel. I need to use `type Employee` in multiple queries and in different schemas. In some cases `Employee` can have extra fields.

```
#employee.graphql

type Employee{
  id: ID
  name: String
}


#company.graphql

extend type Employee{
  loginCount: ID
}
```

Is this good approach? Please suggest me if there is any better way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This is a perfectly acceptable way of doing it although your example is maybe a bit less perfect. Consider something like this though:

```
# employee.graphql

type Employee {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

# company.graphql

type Company {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

extend type Employee {
  company: Company! @belongsTo
}
```

The `loginCount` attribute in your example did not seem related to the `company.graphl`, so for your own sanity try to keep related items grouped.

But having all company related fields and queries in a single file makes a lot of sense especially on bigger schema's.

One sidenote, the added field (`loginCount` in your example and `company` in mine) is added to the `Employee` type wherever you are using it, it's not like that added field is only available within `company.graphql`. When building the final schema all `extend *` types are merged together to a single `Employee` type so the end result of the above results in this schema:

```
type Employee {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  company: Company!
}

type Company {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

Hope it all makes sense!